# Adding multiple attachments to email with paths from txt file via powershell

Tags: powershell

Using powershell I want to scan a folder containing several txt-files (backup logfiles) and in case of an error create an email with the specific txt-files containing the error messages attached to the mail.

at the moment I identify the logfiles and write their path to a seperate txt-file.

```
Get-ChildItem $pfad -Filter *Error*.txt -Recurse | Select-String "Error occured" | Select-Object -expandproperty Path | Out-File -FilePath $filelist
```

I get a txt file containing this (no headers, no blank lines):

```
D:\Share\test2\Neues TextdokumentError.txt
D:\Share\test2\Testfile fbibgfwErroriebgfvibfvsbvf full.txt
```

Then I want to create an e-mail and attach the files from that seperate txt-file.

```
$logfiles = Get-Content $filelist

ForEach($log in $logfiles)
  {
  Write-Host “Attaching File :- ” $log
  $attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment –ArgumentList $log
  $msg.Attachments.Add($attachment)
  }
```

This is the result I keep getting:

```
Attaching File :-  D:\Share\test2\Neues TextdokumentError.txt
Es ist nicht möglich, eine Methode für einen Ausdruck aufzurufen, der den NULL hat.
In C:\test\Unbenannt1.ps1:43 Zeichen:3
+   $msg.Attachments.Add($attachment)
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Attaching File :-  D:\Share\test2\Testfile fbibgfwErroriebgfvibfvsbvf full.txt
Es ist nicht möglich, eine Methode für einen Ausdruck aufzurufen, der den NULL hat.
In C:\test\Unbenannt1.ps1:43 Zeichen:3
+   $msg.Attachments.Add($attachment)
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

In english the error means: "It is not possible to call a method for an expression that has the NULL."

The shown paths are correct, the files are there and they have content.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the System.Net.Mail.Attachment. I personally use the Send-MailMessage cmdlet in PowerShell. But it seems to me that $msg is not declared. Where in your code do you declare $msg?

Comment: does this line >>> `New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment –ArgumentList $log` <<< work? on my system [win7, ps5.1] if fails. however, the next line works if i simply give it a full file path.

Comment: @BernardMoeskops I changed the variable from $msg to $mailmessage in the part where I define the mail-settings and overlooked the old variable in the attachment loop.... for 1.5 hours until I gave up. when I corrected it it instantly worked. thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file paths appear to have spaces in them. What happens if you put `"$log"` in quotes when you define `$attachment`?

**Better solution:** to avoid all that fussing around with parsing strings out of text files, don't output your file list to text. Just use the file system objects.

```
$logfiles = Get-ChildItem $pfad -Filter *Error*.txt -Recurse | Select-String "Error occured" -List | Select Path
```

(Not tested, so check the command returns the files you're looking for)

Comment: it wasn't the quotes (checked that before). I changed the variable from $msk to $mailmessage and didn't change it in the attachment loop. my bad. :( but I changed the part you suggested and it works fine. this way I don't need another txt and take care of deleting it afterwards. thank you!